# How to access to debug mode in Android Phoenix OS on VMware Workstation

Tags: android, debugging

I install Android x86 and Android Phoenix OS on VMware Workstation. Both Freezing in x86_64:/ # and Android doesn't come up But I Found Solution and it's Work. editt kernel and add this "nomodeset xforcevesa"

Now Problem is: in Android x86 in grub menu it has debug mode and I can choose it and go through editing But in Android Phoenix OS there is no debug mode in menu. So How I Access to Debug mode in Phoenix OS? is has any command that i use in CLT to run debug mode?

Please see the images below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to how to go to the debug mode.
but I find the solution to my problem that now I can edit kernel directly.

in the setup section of phoenix os
choose the second option then press tab and now edit where you want to edit

[image]

[image]

Comment: an alternative way is to open iso of phoenix os 
and open efi folder then boot folder and then open grub.cfg file with notepad and edit where you want to edit